# Angular2 Linters Extension for VScode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, lint, linter

I recently came across new term called Linters extensions. During study, I understood that, linter is a small program that checks code for stylistic or programming errors.

I have already used couple of code snippets -

1. Angular 2 snippets from Dan Wahlin.
2. Angular 2 typescript snippets from John papa.

Both of them are really good.

But as a beginner in Angular2 world, I am looking for Linters which will help me programming errors. However I couldnt find one. Are there any Angular2 linters extensions available for VScode?